# Test nginx server with multiple virtual servers

Tags: nginx

I'm preparing a web server that is configured with two virtual servers.
Both of them are listening to ports 80 and 443 and one or the other is served depending on the name you call it with.
That server has a dns name pointing at one of the virtual servers, which is in production.
However, I don't know how to test the secondary virtual server, since it's still not being pointed at by the dns name.
Usually, on a single virtual server environment, I would just point at the IP and see how it responds, but I don't know how to do it now, since when I enter the IP address on a web server, it display one of the servers: I don't know how it decides which one.

Answer (score 1):

Add entries into your local `hosts` file with server IP address and vhost domain names:

```
192.0.2.5 vhost.example.com
```

Then enter vhost domain name into browser address windows and it will go to your server in question, bypassing DNS machinery.

`hosts` file is `/etc/hosts` in unix-like and (i think) `Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in Windows.

Another way to quick-test is to talk HTTP protocol directly: `telnet 192.0.2.5 80`, then in the telnet sessing write:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: vhost.example.com
Connection: close
```

Press `Enter` twice after last line, this double-crlf marks an end of headers in HTTP. You'll get the reply from desired vhost.

Comment: That worked, don't know why i didn't come up with it. Thanks!